# Async Await In Linq .TakeWhile

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert my foreach function to a linq function

here is my normal code [Works fine]

```
    var tList = new List<Func<Task<bool>>> { Method1, Method2 };
    tList.Shuffle();

    int succeed = 0;
    foreach (var task in tList)
    {
        var result = await task();

        if(!result)
            break;

        succeed += 1;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(succeed == 1 ? "Loading complete." : "Something went wrong!");
```

And here is after converted to Linq [Giving 2 compiler errors]

```
    var tList = new List<Func<Task<bool>>> { Method1, Method2 };
    tList.Shuffle();

    int succeed = tList.Select(async task => await task()).TakeWhile(result => result).Count();

    MessageBox.Show(succeed == 1 ? "Loading complete." : "Something went wrong!");
```

Errors

> - Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type    'System.Func,bool>' because some of 
>     the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the
>     delegate return type
> - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'bool'

I wonder why the compiler is giving those messages, so any help will be appreciated.

Note : i also tried `.TakeWhile(async result => await result)` with that error

> - The return type of an async method must be void, Task, or Task T

Method1 and Method2 if someone wanna them :

```
public async Task<bool> Method1()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Method1");
    return false;
}

public async Task<bool> Method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Method2");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## One possible solution

Use a *TakeWhileAsync* extension method like this:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> TakeWhileAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var results = new List<T>();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        var result = await task;
        if (!predicate(result))
            break;

        results.Add(result);
    }

    return results;
}
```

There must be a more optimized solution but this is easy to read in my opinion. You iterate though the tasks, wait for each one to finish then do the same logic the regular *TakeWhile* method does.

First you need to actually call your methods: `tList.Select(func => func()` then apply the extension method over this newly created *IEnumerable<Task<bool>>*: `tList.Select(func => func()).TakeWhileAsync(result => result)`

You then *await* this and count the result: `(await tList.Select(func => func()).TakeWhileAsync(result => result)).Count()`

## Why your attempts did not work

### `.Select(async task => await task()).TakeWhile(result => result)`

Remember that **an async function always returns a Task** (or void). The lambda inside your select block returns an *IEnumerable<Task<bool>>*. When you apply *.TakeWhile* on this, your TakeWhile predicate (`result => result`) also returns a *Task<bool>*, because every element of your sequence at that point **is a Task<bool>**! That causes an error because it should return **bool**.

### `.TakeWhile(async result => await result)`

Same issue, **your lambda returns a Task** (because it is an async "method"), that will never work as a LINQ predicate.

### `.TakeWhile(result => result.Result)`

This one (from Simon's answer) does compile, and will even work in some situations. (Where the SynchronizationContext is not tied to a single thread, but that's another long topic.) The main takeaway however is that **blocking on async code is dangerous** and will potentially lead to **deadlocks**. Here is a [great detailed article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) on this.

Comment: But the drawback is that `TakeWhileAsync` is not lazy like `TakeWhile` is :( I guess we just need to wait for https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/ and the Asynchronous streams feature

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental difference between the first and the second code (which do not do the same thing).

On the first code you are iterating over a list of tasks. On the second you are just transforming each task into another - the return type of an async lambda will always be a task of something.

Because you area awaiting sequentially on each task they really running in sequence. Is that what you intended to do?

Try something like this (not tested):

```
var tList = new List<Func<Task<bool>>> { Method1, Method2 };
tList.Shuffle();

int succeed = Task.WaitAll(tList.ToArray())
    .TakeWhile(result => result).Count();

MessageBox.Show(
    succeed == 1
    ? "Loading complete."
    : "Something went wrong!");
```

But that's still a strange piece of code.

Comment: I want them to run in a sequence.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

int succeed = tList.Select(task => task.Result).TakeWhile(result => result).Count();

Or, probably this:

bool succeed = tList.TakeWhile(task => task.Result).Any();

Answer (score -1):

This is simply because you cannot convert `Task<bool>` to `bool`.. as the compiler has instructed.

Change this:

```
.TakeWhile(result => result)
```

..to this:

```
.TakeWhile(result => result.Result)
```

Comment: But when i use result.Result the UI completely freeze ? any idea ?

Comment: @RuneS the reason your UI freezes is because the compiler thinks your method is not async. After you fix your code like Simon suggested look at the warning in the Error list window "The async method lacks await"

Comment: @Ragzitsu : Not right Rag instead if i used await it says `bool` is not awaitable...

Comment: @RuneS What is your expected output? "Method1", "Method2" and "1"?

Comment: ..and if you want them to run in a sequence.. why then are you writing code that runs them parallel? .. please rephrase what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RuneS you can only await a Task not the Result of a Task. Unless the result of a Task is another Task and in your case it is just a bool.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead this is running in a sequence, and the expected is `awaiting Method1 => returns false so Method2 won't run...`